# Is there a formal CS definition of VCS and file versions?

Tags: terminology, reference-request

I don't know whether it was a joke, but once I read what was referred to as a formal definition of a file in a versioning system such as git, hg or svn. It was something like a mathematical object like a homeomorphism. Was that a joke or is there really computer science theory about versioning systems and the mathematics of VCS?

Comment: I changed homemorphism to homeomorphism, however I have no clue, where to search for topology in this context. Did you mean homomorphism?

Comment: Something like http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_Darcs/Patch_theory or http://projects.haskell.org/camp/ ? It's always a good idea to search for haskell when it comes to theory and programming. I can turn this into an answer, but I think there are people with a better knowledge of this area.

Comment: [Persistent data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure)?

Comment: You do not build something as complex and critical as a versioning system without a strong formalization of what you are doing. People who hack they way may sometimes be geniuses, but usually they are fools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're thinking of [a tweet by Isaac Wolkerstorfer (‏@agnoster)](https://twitter.com/agnoster/status/44636629423497217):

> git gets easier once you get the basic idea that branches are homeomorphic endofunctors mapping submanifolds of a Hilbert space.

Unfortunately, it's a joke. As [the author wrote on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-understand-git-branches-in-terms-of-homeomorphic-endofunctors-mapping-submanifolds-of-a-Hilbert-space?share=1):

> It was intended as firmly tongue-in-cheek. I actually love git, and I think its complexity is greatly overblown. At the same time, I'm sympathetic to the fact that advice from git gurus to novices can end up sounding like inscrutable gibberish.
>
> It's not intended to have any deeper meaning. Attempts to analyze it in this fashion should be futile, but due to a bug in reality, you can actually make any sufficiently hand-wavy statement fit if you try hard enough.

This has been discussed [on Programmers Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/256450/are-git-branches-in-fact-homeomorphic-endofunctors-mapping-submanifolds-of-a) and [on Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675092/does-this-statement-about-hilbert-spaces-make-any-sense).

---

Joke aside, there has been work of formalizing version control. One effort that allies theory and practice is the work on **patch theory** by David Roundy on [Darcs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcs). The main objective of the theory is to model merging and, in particular, conflict resolution. The [Darcs wiki](http://darcs.net/Theory) has an introduction to the theory and a few pointers as well as a [bibliography](http://darcs.net/Theory/Bibliography) (unmaintained so outdated if you want a recent view on the subject, but it does list a [2009 survey paper by Petr Baudiš](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.3496.pdf)) and a list of [talks](http://darcs.net/Talks) (which includes more recent material). There's also a [wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Understanding_Darcs/Patch_theory). One seminal paper is [*A Principled Approach to Version Control* by Andres Löh, Wouter Swierstra and Daan Leijen3](http://www.andres-loeh.de/fase2007.pdf).

Patch theory does lead to a categorical model, which has been more recently explored in [*A Categorical Theory of Patches* by Samuel Mimram and Cinzia Di Giusto](http://www.pps.univ-paris-diderot.fr/%7Esmimram/docs/mimram_ctp.pdf) and [*Homotopical Patch Theory* by Carlo Angiuli, Ed Morehouse, Daniel R. Licata and Robert Harper](http://dlicata.web.wesleyan.edu/pubs/amlh14patch/amlh14patch.pdf). In Mimram and Di Giusto's work, the model has files as objects and patches as morphisms. I think that makes merging a branch a functor — an endofunctor if you're working in a single repository. “Homeomorphic endofunctor” doesn't make sense to me. With homotopy theory involved, submanifolds of a Hilbert space might not be so far out...

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is a mathematical formalism for version control systems. There is a mathematical formalism for virtually every algorithm in CS. There are *multiple* formalisms for many. There is not a 1-1 relationship between formalisms and the systems they [model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_(abstract)). The models can range from simple to complex. Here is an example for VCS/[SCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_management) also by Swierstra, not cited yet.

- [The Semantics of Version Control](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~swier004/Publications/versionControl.pdf)

SCM also has a lot of similarities to the concept of ["parallel universes/ timelines"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternate_history) and [time travel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_travel) sometimes used in science fiction. It captures the state of the evolving system at different times or "snapshots". There are "branches" and "merges". See also [timelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timelines).